# Calling multiple instances of python scripts in matlab using java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime not working

Tags: java, python, matlab, multiprocessing

I am running Matlab2017 on windows 10.
I call a python script that runs some Speech Recognition task on cloud with something like this:

```
 userAuthCode=1;% authentication code for user account to be run on cloud
 cmd = ['C:\Python27\python.exe runASR.py userAuthCode];  
 system(cmd);
```

When the above command is called, the python script runs the input audio file on the ASR cloud engine, and as it runs, I can see Speech Recognition scores for the audio file from Python in the Matlab console.
 I want to do the following:

(1) Execute multiple such commands in parallel. Lets say, I have 2 input audio files (each having different audio segments), and I would like to run the above command 2 times, but in parallel, using separate processes. I was able to create a code snippet that should be able to do this:

```
 for i=1: 2
     userAuthCode=i;
     cmd = ['C:\Python27\python.exe runASR.py userAuthCode];  
     runtime = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();        
     pid(i) = runtime.exec(cmd);
 end

 for i=1:2
    pid(i).waitFor();
    % get exit status
    rc(i) = pid(i).exitValue();       
 end
```

Now, when the above code is executed, I can see ASRE scores for data1 ,but not for data 2.
 The exit status in variable *rc*, is *0,1,* which confirms this.
 The problem is I do not know the cause of the error, as nothing is printed in 
 Matlab. How can I get error message from Python captured in a java/Matlab 
 variable so that i could take a look?

The issue could be that multiple Calls to 
 ASRE in parallel (with different user accounts of course) may not 
 be supported but I won't know unless I can see the error.

(2) When I run a single command standalone, as mentioned at the start of the post, I am able to see Score messages for each audio segment being printed in the Matlab console, as they are obtained from Python. However, with multi-processing using *java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()* and the associated code, no messages appears in the Matlab console. Is there a way to display those messages (I am assuming display might be asynchronous?)

Thanks
sedy

Comment: did you try replacing the for loop with a parfor loop? That should spawn individual matlab processes similar to `!matlab &`

Comment: I will try that.(Would parfor work if I dont have parallel computing toolbox?) Also, is there a way to pipe Python error messages to Matlab when using java runtime engine?

Comment: it would work without yes, but AFAIK not as efficient. piping the error messages will be harder, surpasses my knowledge. let us know if it works =)

Comment: perhaps you can try a different approach : python has good support for running matlab. you could try using python as the running framework instead of matlab, in order to get better control of what is happening. is this feasible on your end ?

Comment: Hi Rann. I dont have that option as there is  some other DSP simulation framework that already is built into Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried this ?
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.exception.pyexception-class.html?requestedDomain=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use multiprocessing in Python. The results and any error messages can be returned in a list.

**Example:**

Assuming you have three audio files, `your_function` will run 3 times in parallel with error messages returned.

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def multi_processor(function_name):

    # Use a regex to make a list of full paths for audio files in /some/directory
    # You could also just pass in a list of audio files as a parameter to this function
    file_list = []
    file_list = str(subprocess.check_output("find ./some/directory -type f -iname \"*a_string_in_your_aud_file_name*\" ",shell=True)).split('\\n')
    file_list = sorted(file_list)

    # Test, comment out two lines above and put 3 strings in the list so your_function should run three times with 3 processors in parallel
    file_list.append("test1")
    file_list.append("test2")
    file_list.append("test3")

    # Use max number of system processors - 1
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count()-1)
    pool.daemon = True

    results = {}
    # for every audio file in the file list, start a new process
    for aud_file in file_list:
        results[aud_file] = pool.apply_async(your_function, args=("arg1", "arg2"))

    # Wait for all processes to finish before proceeding
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Results and any errors are returned
    return {your_function: result.get() for your_function, result in results.items()}


def your_function(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        print("put your stuff in this function")
        your_results = ""
        return your_results
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi_processor("your_function")
```